# Can't install mysql server on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, mysql

I'm trying to install a mysql server on my win 10 machine. I've downloaded the installer from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), but when I open it, it finds an installed version of mysql server on my computer (which I thought I had uninstalled something like a month ago). I tried to remove it from the installer, but it fails when it reaches 50%, and I also cannot find any mysql file on my computer. Can anyone of you help me removing the thing I have on my computer to make a new fresh install on mysql server, please?

Thanks,

Lorenzo

P.S. the error when I try to remove is

> 1: The action 'Remove' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.13' failed

Comment: Try the Windows FixIt for when a program has problems being removed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end FixIt did the trick, as @Kinnectus advised. Thanks to all

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/803230)

Comment: @PeterH unfortunately in this case the answer was posted as a comment so this actually *is* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making sure you are up to date with windows or reinstalling it entirely to remove mysql. You could also try installing a different sql server, like postgresql, as it wouldn't find a previous install. https://www.postgresql.org/

Comment: I will try with postgresql, but it seems strange I would need to reinstall entirely windows to remove a bad installation of mysql

Comment: It is not preferable, but without more information this is hard to troubleshoot. Postgresql should work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the event viewer for a more detailed error report, this might give you the reason why it wasnt installed. Or if it means nothing google the error report and you may find the answer on google.